# Second For-Each does not return any data

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a script that returns data post maintenance window, if the service is pinging, last reboot time, and if services are running. My second for-each does not return any data when in my script just blank return, below is my script.

```
#### Provide the computer name in $computername variable 

$ServerName = (Get-Content -Path "\\Server\d$\Data\Admin\Scripts\MW 
scripts\Primary.txt")

$ServerNameB = (Get-Content -Path "\\Server\d$\Data\Admin\Scripts\MW 
scripts\Primarylessalt.txt")

##### Script Starts Here ######  


foreach ($Server in $ServerName) { 

    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet ) {  

        write-Host "$Server is alive and Pinging " -ForegroundColor Green 

                } else 

                { Write-Warning "$Server is dead and not pinging" 

                }     

} 

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) { (Get-Service -Name "Print Spooler" -Cn 
$Server) | Select name,status,machinename}

foreach ($Server in $ServerNameB){Get-CimInstance -Cn $Server -ClassName 
win32_operatingsystem | select csname,lastbootuptime}



Format-Table -AutoSize
Write-Host "Script is complete" -ForegroundColor Cyan

Read-Host "Press Enter to Exit"




########## end of script #######################
```

Comment: Can you please format your code? That is very difficult to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple tables with different columns tends to confuse the output parser.  You can force it to flush the results with `Format-Table`:

```
foreach ($Server in $ServerName) { (Get-Service -Name "Print Spooler" -Cn 
$Server) | Select name,status,machinename  | Format-Table -AutoSize}

foreach ($Server in $ServerNameB){Get-CimInstance -Cn $Server -ClassName 
win32_operatingsystem | select csname,lastbootuptime  | Format-Table -AutoSize}
```